# Order of condition execution in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have a MySQL query with two conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field_1` = 1 AND `field_2` LIKE '%term%';
```

The first condition is obviously going to be a lot cheaper than the second, so I'd like to be sure that it runs first, limiting the pool of rows which will be compared with the LIKE clause. Do MySQL query conditions run in the order they're listed or, if not, is there a way to specify order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL has an internal query optimizer that takes care of such things in most cases.  So, typically, you don't need to worry about it.

But, of course, the query optimizer is not foolproof.  So...

Sorry to do this to you, but you'll want to get familiar with `EXPLAIN` if you suspect that a query may be running less efficiently than it should.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Not diagnosing a specific query, just mulling over the possibility. Thanks for the EXPLAIN tip, I'll have to read up on it.

Answer (score 9):

The optimiser will evaluate the WHERE conditions in the order it sees fit.

SQL is [declarative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming): you tell the optimiser *what* you want, not *how* to do it.

In a [procedural/imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) language (.net, Java, php etc) then you say *how* and would choose which condition is evaluated first.

Note: "left to right" does apply in certain expressions like `(a+b)*c` as you'd expect

Comment: Exactly, also you cannot use the order of MySQL condition execution as the 'or condition', in procedural languages, you can use `if(a==1 || b==3)..`, once `a==1`, `b==3` will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have doubts about MySQL usage of index, you can suggest what index should be used.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html