# How does SQL LIKE actually work

Tags: mysql, sql

For example when I have a string like this:

```
ABBBCSLAK**JDK**ASAAAAFJKDSKJFSDF
```

And when I use SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%JDK%'
```

What exactly happens when server gets to JDK? Does it stop and execute the SQL or does it go through the rest of the string and then execute the SQL?

Also what happends when I have multiple LIKE clauses in my SQL statement connected with OR? Does it stop at first LIKE clause when it is possitive?

Edit:
I have SQL like this. It is probably overkill but wel... Every variable contains loop of LIKE clauses for one table column. They have "OR" in between of them. Whether I change these "ANDs" to "AND" or "OR" does not make any difference.

```
                     WHERE
                        ($countrySQL)
                            AND
                        ($schools_typeSQL)
                            AND
                        $schoolsSQL
                            AND
                        $schools_facultiesSQL
                            AND
                        $schools_classesSQL
                    ORDER BY
```

Comment: I'm sure MySQL doesn't do more than needed: if the condition is true for one row have a look at the next. An index can't be used with such a search pattern.

Comment: Sorry but did you give me minus? Why do people even do that? This is totally relevant question.

Comment: I didn't. I was commenting only and gave a hint of the performance brake. But nobody has to account for the voting.

Comment: Ah sorry then. My fault.

Comment: I just hate to see all those down votes every time I ask here something. I am coding in my spare time. Peopel should realise that.

Comment: You might try to focus more on a specific aspect of your question. Don't know if my answer even covers halve of what you ask since the last edit.

Comment: You would better post an example table with some rows and a minimal query that illustrates your problem: the result you expect and the result you get. There's still too much room for interpretation.

Comment: Thanks I mainly wanted to know how will this complicated SQL affect performance. MrTux and Constructor gave me great answers. Some two jerks downvoted me not knowing how SQL works... Second problem was just in my head because such conditions couldn't happen. In order to $schools_classesSQL to be true $countrySQL must be true as well. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL tries to [improve the speed of `LIKE` when a B-Tree index is available](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-btree-hash.html) by pre-filtering the rows:

> ### B-Tree Index Characteristics
>
> A B-tree index can be used for column comparisons in expressions that use the `=`, `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, or `BETWEEN` operators. The index also can be used for `LIKE` comparisons if the argument to `LIKE` is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character. For example, the following `SELECT` statements use indexes:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE 'Patrick%';
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE 'Pat%_ck%';
> ```
>
> In the first statement, only rows with 'Patrick' <= key_col < 'Patricl' are considered. In the second statement, only rows with 'Pat' <= key_col < 'Pau' are considered.
>
> The following SELECT statements do not use indexes:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE '%Patrick%';
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE other_col;
> ```
>
> In the first statement, the LIKE value begins with a wildcard character. In the second statement, the LIKE value is not a constant.
>
> If you use ... `LIKE '%string%'` and string is longer than three characters, MySQL uses the *Turbo Boyer-Moore algorithm* to initialize the pattern for the string and then uses this pattern to perform the search more quickly.

If you have multiple `OR`-connected terms, query optimization will try to find the optimal query path and may reorder the conditions or even decide to handle them one by one. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327510/order-of-condition-execution-in-mysql) for details.

Answer (score 0):

This, of course, depends on the implementation of the database management system (DMBS).

However, most DBMS are optimized for performance and, thus, they use short circuits. I.e. if one argument in (a OR B) is true, it stops evaluating the rest of it, because it's already true. Same for (A AND B) if A is false, it doesn't need to check for B since the whole expression cannot be true any more.

Same would also apply for the LIKE operator. There is no need to go on checking a string if a match was already found.

Besides that:
SQL is a declarative "language" and, thus, you don't know if it's altered/optimized to a better one by the DBMS (e.g., another column is checked first because the DBMS has an index for this column).

Comment: Thanks for you answer and ... I found that when I have multiple clauses "LIKE 1(exists) LIKE 2(does not exist) LIKE 3(exists)" it returns the table row. However when I change order like this "LIKE 2(does not exist) LIKE 1(exists) LIKE 3(exists)" the row is not returned. Is there anyway how to force server to check for every LIKE so that every LIKE clause would have to be positive?

Comment: WHERE column1 LIKE 'aa' AND column2 LIKE 'bb', then both likes have to match.

Comment: I already tried that it did not work. I will edit my question in a second so that you could see my problem in more details if you have a spare minute. :)