# SQL where-clause speed up

Tags: mysql, sql

This query

```
UPDATE table
SET stringcol = REPLACE(stringcol, 'tester1', 'tester2')
WHERE stringcol LIKE '%tester1%'
```

runs almost twice as fast (on a large table) as this one

```
UPDATE table
SET stringcol = REPLACE(stringcol, 'tester1', 'tester2')
```

where only the `WHERE` clause has been omitted.

I think this is a very strange result.

In the first query, the database must first search every `stringcol` in the table for an occurrence of `tester1`. Then, a reduced subset of the table is passed to the `REPLACE` function, which needs to find `tester1` again in order to replace it.

In the second query, the database engine must search every `stringcol` in the table for an occurrence of `tester1`, and replace accordingly.

If anything, I would expect the first query to run slower, as both the `WHERE` clause and the `REPLACE` function check for an occurrence of `tester1`.

I suppose my analysis of how the database handles the queries is too simplistic. Can someone explain the difference in performance?

Comment: `REPLACE` is slow, and `LIKE` is fast. You first narrow down the records that need to have the slower `REPLACE` run on them and you get a faster result. Just imagine that `REPLACE` has to look at EVERY record passed to it to find 'tester1' regardless of whether it has `tester1` in it.

Comment: This might be helpful for you. [How does SQL LIKE actually work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171013/how-does-sql-like-actually-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query with no `WHERE` clause applies the replace to *every* row in the table. This means that for every record, you are take a lock on the area of disk where `stringcol` is stored for that row and fetching the contents, performing the replace, and writing it back. Depending on the DB, this may occur even if there is no change to data. This may be smart because it might take longer to verify if there there has been a change than writing it to disk. Also, since the single statement is updating every record, the DB will create a transaction log of every change.

Adding the `WHERE` clause will at least filter each row before making the change. Even though the `LIKE '%value%'` does not use an index, the DB will check the value of the field before acquiring the lock and updating the value. This probably results in a very large reduction in the number of rows locked and changes applied.

Comment: Thanks for some info on the additional overhead of `REPLACE`!