# What is the order of execution of Mysql query with multiple and clause?

Tags: mysql, performance

Like, if you have a query

```
select * from employee where name = "John Dao" and location = "New York" and salary > 1000
```

In this query how the `AND` clause works. Will it fetch first the result set with name John Dao and perform a filter on the fetched result set for location and so on.
OR 
Does it just fetch results where it satisfies all conditions?

Is there any change in the query response if we change the order of `AND` statements in a query?

Comment: This is unpredictable. And may be changed in any time due to data and statistic change.

Comment: I think your model of _when_ the "result set is fetched" is flawed.  See my Answer for a better way to think of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of condition execution in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327510/order-of-condition-execution-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the various terms in the `WHERE` clause are executed is non deterministic, and you cannot rely on things like short-circuiting (as you might expect in application languages such as Java and C#).  If you really wanted to ensure logical evaluation in a certain order, you could use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE
    CASE WHEN name <> 'John dao'     THEN 0
         WHEN location <> 'New York' THEN 0
         WHEN salary <= 1000         THEN 0
         ELSE 1 END = 1;
```

The `CASE` expression above first checks the name requirement, and fails if the name be not `John dao`.  Next, it checks the location, followed by the salary, all in this order.  But, the order of evaluation in the following `WHERE` clause is undefined:

```
WHERE name = 'John dao' AND location = 'New York' AND salary > 1000
```

In general, though, a good database should choose the order of evaluation in such a way that it makes the `WHERE` clause execute the fastest.  That is, normally you should not need to resort to the `CASE` expression trick I used above.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE name = 'John dao'
  AND location = 'New York'
  AND salary > 1000
```

**Case 1, no relevant index:**  It will fetch all the rows, checking the 3 columns until one fails or they all succeed.  The order of checks is insignificant unless there are complex issues, such as UDFs, FULLTEXT, subqueries, non-deterministic functions, etc.  Numeric and string, equal and not equal are insignificant.

**Case 2: a separate `INDEX` on each of those 3 columns:**  The Optimizer will use the available (albeit crude) statistics to decide which of the 3 clauses will be filter out the most rows.  Then the other two checks will be done against the data by using the `PRIMARY KEY` (which is implicitly tacked onto the index) to locate the data row in the data's BTree.  From the row, it can get the other two columns to finish the filtering.  It is very rare for MySQL to use multiple indexes in this situation.

**Case 3: `INDEX(name, location, salary)` or `INDEX(location, name, salary)`:**  Either of these is optimal for performing the query.  Note that the columns tested with `=` are first *in the `INDEX`, regardless of order in the `WHERE`*.  It will drill down the BTree to the first John dao in New York with Salary > 1000.  Then it will scan forward in the B+Tree to find all such rows.  Assuming `*` (of `SELECT *`) involves more than those 3 columns, Case 3 will then have to reach over into the data BTree to fetch the rest of the columns.  Note that this is better than Case 2 because it does all the filtering before reaching into the other BTree.

More on devising optimal indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql